# Soap request with namespace

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I have web service client and when i send request, the soap message looks like

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<S:Body>
<Open xmlns="ttt:some:namespace">
   <PartnerName>SomeParther</PartnerName>
   <NumberToS>1</NumberToS>
</Open>
</S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

and this incorrect message. The correct message looks like

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
 xmlns:urn="ttt:some:namespace">
<soapenv:Header /> 
<soapenv:Body>
<ttt:Open>
  <ttt:PartnerName>SomeParther</ttt:PartnerName> 
  <ttt:NumberToS>1</ttt:NumberToS> 
</ttt:Open>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

how i do soap request

```
    So_Service soService = new So_Service();
    SoPort soPort = soService.getSoaphaSOAP();
    /*  test */
    System.out.println("getServiceName from So_Service" + soService.getServiceName());
    soPort.open("SomeParther", 1);
```

output getServiceName from So_Service ttt:some:namespace

What I'm doing wrong? What should i do for correct generate the message? Please Help

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
 xmlns:urn="ttt:some:namespace">
<soapenv:Header /> 
<soapenv:Body>
<urn:Open>
  <urn:PartnerName>SomeParther</urn:PartnerName> 
  <urn:NumberToS>1</urn:NumberToS> 
</urn:Open>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Can you tell you write kSOUP request for complex request with namespace?